# Is it possible to store the variable type?

Tags: c++, templates, keyword

So I have a templated function that I want to define the type dynamically.

```
something_that_holds_type type;
obj.GetComponent<type>();
```

Is it possible?
I also thought of smothing like this:

```
#define GETTYPE(t) t
obj.GetComponent<GETTYPE(int)>();
```

This works, but that doesn't help. What I would like to do was to pass the type name and converte it into a keyword, similar to this:

```
#define GETTYPE(t) removes_quatation_marks_of_t
obj.GetComponent<GETTYPE("int")>();
```

Is any of this possible in c++?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? The type has to be known at compile time anyway, so these macros just seem to make things more difficult

Comment: Just write `int` bro

Comment: Tell us what you're _really_ trying to do. Something like a `std::variant` may be of use to you but we have no way of knowing really

Comment: [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) (in [`#include <typeinfo>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo)) and `typeid(Foo)` may do what you want.  Not cross-compiler compatible, if you want to share across platforms or for persistent storage.

Comment: I have a class Entity class. That class can have and access just one component at the time: Box Collider, Sphere Collider, Mesh Collider etc. But I wouldn't like declare every collider component that I could have in the Entity class. So I've created a void* that points to one of the collider classes.  In order to access the data correctly I have to know the types at runtime as I plan to chage the collider at runtime too. I want a function that returns a pointer to the collider, thats' beacause I have a template

Comment: @Corelli Then you should use `std::variant`, polymorphism or the visitor pattern or some of the other language tools to deal with that kind of situation.

Comment: @Corelli It seems that you want runtime polymorphism via virtual member functions. `Collider` would be a base class with virtual destructor and virtual interface. The specific `Collider` types will be derived from it and implement the virtual interface. `Entity` will take a `Collider*` (or `std::unqiue_ptr<Collider>` if owning) instead of a `void*` and then you won't ever need to know the actual object's type inside `Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

No what you describe cannot be done.

Variations of what you ask can be done, but to describe it we'd have to see something more concrete than your abstract description.